# What we need to create CORS?

Tags: javascript, cors

I've confused between this CORS?? :-(

I just ask a little help from you. What is the complete source code for XMLHttpRequest using javascript CORS. How I get json data from a server that sent. If I can access to the json file using address bar. How I get those data from it?

**Here Is Json File "Data.json"**

```
{"JsonProjectIDResult": [{"_capacity": 15,"_description": "Meeting Room","_dev_default_view": 3,"_deviceID": 1,"_deviceName": "MobiTech","_deviceTypeID": 1,"_projectID": 1,"_roomID": 2,"_roomName": "Room2","_room_admin_mail": null}]}
```

**Here My home.html simple script**

```
var resultDiv = document.getElementById("results");
var newsURL = "http://10.1.128.106/JsonDohaBackToTemplate/getProjectIDByMAC.svc/mac/10:95:84:11:00:05";
var e;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    e = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    e = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
e.onreadystatechange = function() {
    var html = " ";
    if (e.readyState == 4 && e.status == 200) {
        response = JSON.parse(e.responseText);

        if(typeof(e.responseText)==="string") {
            d = e.responseText;
        } else {
            if (typeof(e.responseXML)==="object") {
                d = e.responseXML;
            };
        }
        var myData = response['JsonProjectIDResult'];
        //Loop
        var html = "<ul>";
        var counter = 0;
        for(var prop in myData[counter]) {
            if(myData[counter].hasOwnProperty(prop))
            html += "<li>" + prop + " = " + myData[counter][prop] + "</li>";
        }
        resultDiv.innerHTML = html;
    }
};
e.open("GET", newsURL, true);
e.send();
```

Comment: what is on your server?

Comment: CORS is something you need to set up on the server.  Have a look at http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CORS requires no changes to the JavaScript. It is handled with HTTP headers sent by the server the request is being made to.

i.e. `example.com` has JavaScript that wants to read from `example.net`. `example.net` must use CORS to give permission to `example.com` to read that data.

At its most basic, `example.net` needs to include:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
```

in the response headers.

More complex situations may require the setting of those headers for a pre-flight OPTIONS request too.

More details can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).